# how to add custom css as default for the whole site

Tags: theming

How can I add my css file as default for the whole Drupal site?

Where to put my CSS file so that it applies to whole Drupal 7 site that I am creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it on every theme, then you'll want it in a module.

Using this method you won't have to put the CSS in with every theme - just add and enable the module.

Just create a module that uses the following code:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page($vars) {
  $options = array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'every_page' => TRUE
  );
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/MYGLOBALCSS.css', $options);
  $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
}
```

[`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)

[`drupal_get_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_css/7)

You'll need to clear your theme registry to have the changes picked up.

Comment: Will it be applicable to whole site......

Comment: Yes.  So long as the module is active - which it will be regardless of the chosen theme.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a stylesheet to your theme folder in a folder named 'css' for example, then in your YOURTHEME.info file you need to make a reference to it like...

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/default.css
```

Comment: That means I have to write in Info file of all themes so that when user changes theme, custom css should also be available.

Comment: What you want to do is have a 'base' theme with your default styles then you can create any number of 'sub' themes while retaining the default 'base' theme within them.